# Object passed through ng-click function loses reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When passing an object to a `ng-click` function, the object seems to lose its reference. **What is the reason?**

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpoLvO)

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <p>
    <u>Object</u> : {{ obj | json }}
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ng-click="obj = {}">obj = {}</button> <!-- works -->
    <button ng-click="voidIt(obj)">voidIt(obj)</button> <!-- doesn't work -->
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset obj</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('controller',
function($scope) {

  $scope.voidIt = function(object) {
    object = {}
  }

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.obj = { prop: "value" }
  }

  $scope.reset();

});
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: The reason is : on your `voidIt` function, your set object to {}, not `$scope.obj`. So your object is empty meanwhile `$scope.obj` remains the same.

Comment: @Vineet The question is: why?

Comment: @Apédémak I get that, but shouldn't `obj`, in the view, reference `$scope.obj`?

Comment: Everything seems to work fine. If you are wondering why pressing `voidIt(obj)` after pressing `obj = {}` doesn't do anything, it's because you are emptying your `obj`

Comment: No, he's wondering why VoidIt doesn't work, EVER. It does not keep reference with the obj and object (which should reference same object)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: @Apédémak As far as i understand, I can mess with `object` but shouldn't reassign it in any way (`object =` is banned) if I want to keep the reference, is that right? Edited, working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvzBWe

Comment: That's rigth, you can modify the attribute `prop` like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdLqqO but you can't really do more by reference.

Answer (score 0):

What a nested `$scope` refers to can become confusing, so it's much better to use the `controllerAs` syntax. For a good explanation, [read AngularJS 'controllerAs' vs. '$scope'](http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/).

[The Codepen with ControllerAs referencing](http://codepen.io/ShMcK/pen/bdvymy).

But if you're looking for a clear reasoning why it doesn't work, I'm lost as well. I just find it's just better to take the safer path that avoids such pitfalls.